# How to create an incidence array from random array objects?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance, search

Given the following:

```
var dataSource = [
   {X: 0, Y: 0, ApiKey: "Something"},
   {X: 100, Y: 0, ApiKey: "Something"},
   {X: 1500, Y: 200, ApiKey: "Something"},
   {X: 1600, Y: 850, ApiKey: "Something"},
   {X: 0, Y: 750, ApiKey: "Something"},
   {X: 0, Y: 800, ApiKey: "Something"},
];
```

I need to create a new array indicating from range how many incidents there were:

```
var result = [
  {fromX: 0, ToX: 500, incidence: 4},
  {fromX: 1500, ToX: 2000, incidence: 2}
];
```

I created an iterative solution, the problem is when data source have 15000 objects it takes over 8-12 minutes! In Node.js. Anyone know a better solution?

Comment: include your solution. sounds like it's N^2 you can do this in N time

Comment: is `ToX` inclusive? or is `x >= 0 && x <= 500` or `x >= 0 && x < 500`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give an interval and use a hash table for the calculated interval and the count.

```js
var dataSource = [{ X: 0, Y: 0, ApiKey: "Something" }, { X: 100, Y: 0, ApiKey: "Something" }, { X: 1500, Y: 200, ApiKey: "Something" }, { X: 1600, Y: 850, ApiKey: "Something" }, { X: 0, Y: 750, ApiKey: "Something" }, { X: 0, Y: 800, ApiKey: "Something" }],
    interval = 500,
    grouped = [];
  
dataSource.forEach(function(a) {
    var key = Math.floor(a.X / interval);
    if (!this[key]) {
        this[key] = { fromX: key * interval, toX: (key + 1) * interval, incidence: 0 },
        grouped.push(this[key]);
    }
    this[key].incidence++;
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(grouped);
```

With interval for `X` and `Y`.

```js
var dataSource = [{ X: 0, Y: 0, ApiKey: "Something" }, { X: 100, Y: 0, ApiKey: "Something" }, { X: 1500, Y: 200, ApiKey: "Something" }, { X: 1600, Y: 850, ApiKey: "Something" }, { X: 0, Y: 750, ApiKey: "Something" }, { X: 0, Y: 800, ApiKey: "Something" }],
    interval = 500,
    grouped = [];
  
dataSource.forEach(function(a) {
    var keyX = Math.floor(a.X / interval),
        keyY = Math.floor(a.Y / interval),
        key = keyX + '|' + keyY;
    if (!this[key]) {
        this[key] = {
            fromX: keyX * interval,
            toX: (keyX + 1) * interval,
            fromY: keyY * interval,
            toY: (keyY + 1) * interval,
            incidence: 0
        },
        grouped.push(this[key]);
    }
    this[key].incidence++;
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Very nice, but I don't understand :( because I need add a new variable ("Y")

Comment: what do you mean by *I need add a new variable ("Y")*?

Comment: Well, thanks to you I can get results [{fromX: 0, ToX: 500, incidence: 4},...] but now I need understand the code to get something like: [{fromX: 0, ToX: 500, fromY:0, toY: 500, incidence: 4}...]

Comment: @CamiRodriguez, please see edit. it works now for areas.

Comment: Wonderful! now its possible

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using D3 as it optimise some methods such as groupby

```
d3.nest()
    .key(_ => _)
    .rollup(leaves => leaves.length)
    .entries(dataSource.map(_ => _.X / 1500 | 0))
    .map(_ => { return {
        'fromX':_.key * 500,
        'ToX': (1 + _.key) * 500, 
        'incidence': _.values
    }})
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you extend the `dataSource` array, so every time you push a incidence into the `dataSource`, it will be recorded.

```
dataSource = [];
dataSource.ix = [];
dataSource.result = [];
dataSource.push = function(o) {
    if (ix[o.X] !== undefined)
        ix[o.X]++;
    else ix[o.X] = 1;
    Array.prototype.push.call(this, o);
};
dataSource.calculate = function(a, b) {
    var i, r = {
        fromX: a,
        ToX: b,
        incidence: 0
    };
    for (i = a; i <= b; i++) {
        if (this.ix[i])
            r.incidence += this.ix[i];
    }
    this.result.push(r);
};
```